# How to gather all the images in flutter?

Tags: image, flutter

I tried to this using path_provider package and image_picker package.
But I couldn't gather image files that user has.

How can I get all the image files from mobile? It is necessary for my project.

Comment: The question is far too broad. Specify where you want the files to get from. And exactly what you want. Also add the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

It would not be an appropriate ans to your ques but as far as i know there is no plugin created yet with which you can load all the images on the device storage . The developers are still working on flutter and new plugins are being developed everyday . But for your purpose there is no plugin yet . To check other plugins available you can go to [Dart Plugins](https://pub.dartlang.org/)